# Who's the giant Batman in the back of this "Dark Nights: Metal" Batman picture?

Tags: dc, batman, character-identification, dark-nights-metal

I have found websites that describe all the other Batmen but not the giant, cloaked Batman in the back of this *Dark Nights: Metal #2* panel. Who is this Batman, and what multiverse are they from?

[image: "Dark Nights: Metal #2" panel with various Batmen in the background, including a vampire Robin; the foreground has Wonder Woman and Superman crawling on the floor. In the very back of the Batmen is a large, cloaked Grim Reaper-style Batman.]

Answer (score 14):

That's [**Barbatos**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Barbatos_(Dark_Multiverse)), otherwise know as ***the Bat-God***. He comes from the Dark Multiverse.

[image: Barbatos in the background towering over a city skyline with his massive wings spread; Superman lays potentially dead in the foreground on a garbage heap]